# Enforce a specific version of a third-party assembly

Tags: c#, .net, dll, gac

I have an application that relies on a set of third-party DLLs, version `v1.1`. In order to use them, I reference the main one, which is found somewhere under the Program Files folder. This library uses the other ones, installed in the GAC.

A new version of the third-party DLLs is released, `v1.2`. The DLL in the Program Files folder is replaced by the new version; in the GAC, both versions co-exist.

The problem is to get the application (compiled with DLLs `v1.1`) to work when `v1.2` is installed, without re-compiling it, and without changing the `app.exe.config` file.

I am the maintainer of the DLLs; additional constraints are that only the latest version of the DLL is installed in Program Files, and other DLLs are all installed in the GAC (all versions are kept).

My problem is that the application starts, but eventually I get an error because of incompatibilities between types:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException:
[A]ThirdParty.User cannot be cast to [B]ThirdParty.User.
Type A originates from 'ThirdParty, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXX'
in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\ThirdParty\v4.0_1.2.0.0__XXXX\ThirdParty.dll'.
Type B originates from 'ThirdParty, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXX'
in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\ThirdPart\v4.0_1.1.0.0__XXXX\ThirdParty.dll'.
```

I am not sure to understand how the `v1.2` DLL is chosen, I am guessing that the path to the DLL is stored in the application, which in turn decides to use the DLLs in the GAC for this version? I am testing on a system different from the one used for compiling, but the DLLs are located in the same location. My understanding from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx) is that the `v1.1` version in the GAC should be chosen, not `v1.2`.

Where is my mistake? How can I fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: Pretty standard DLL Hell.  *Somehow* a v1.2 object got created, even though you don't target it.  A simple way to find the evil-doer is by making v1.2 inaccessible, remove it from the GAC.  Now it should bomb because it can't find the DLL anymore.  But pretty likely you'll have to send the author a bug report.

Comment: @HansPassant I am the maintainer of this hell...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in my specific case, and re-reading my question I realize I did not mention that my initial DLL does rely on a `PowerShell` instance. Which is where I worked around my problem. In my DLL, I load a specific version if the DLL that is present in the GAC, and load it in my `PowerShell` instance:

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load("ThirdParty, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXX");
var ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Commands.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddParameter("-Assembly", assembly);
ps.Invoke();
```